# Sort Array of 0 ,1 and 2

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

What is wrong in my code why it is not giving correct output??

input

```
84
1 0 1 2 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 1 2 2 0 0 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 2 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 1 2 2 2 0 2 1 1 2 2 0 2 2 1 1 0 0 2 0 2 2 1 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 2 0 2 1 0 0 2 2
```

Its Correct output is:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

And Your Code's output is:

```
0-36092119132636100007056629140-858993460214748364-...
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void sortArray(int *arr,int n){
    int low=0,mid=1,high=n-1;
    while(mid<=high){
        if(arr[mid]==1){
            mid++;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]==2){
            swap(arr[mid],arr[high]);
            high--;
        }
        else{
            swap(arr[mid],arr[low]);
            mid++,low++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i];
    }
}
int main()
 {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>arr[n];
        }
        sortArray(arr,n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you really want to implement the the algorithm yourself ? i mean you can just use the builtin standard library function or if you really want to implement yourself then please study the quick sort algorithm, i figured out you are trying to use it

Comment: @ArishKhan This might be homework to learn the algorithm...

Comment: Look at the `cin` within the loop and think. Also the array declaration is not standard C++, maybe use `std::vector` instead. And do learn how to run code line by line in a debugger checking all the variables and changes to them. It helps determine where things go wrong.

Comment: Note that your algorithm will not properly sort the array `{2, 1}`.

Comment: The most important omission from the code presented is a description what it is to accomplish. (And yes, requirements specification can be incomplete, even erroneous. Embedded in the code or not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is in your input reading:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>arr[n];
}
```

You are reading into `arr[n]` which is [undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You want to use `i` as index:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];
}
```

Since the array is going to contain only 0, 1, or 2, you can simplify the sorting algorithm, too:

```
void sortArray(int *arr, size_t n)
{
    size_t count[3] = {0};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       count[arr[i]]++;
    }

    size_t k = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < count[i]; ++j)
            arr[k++] = i;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';

    std::cout << endl;
}
```

Note: you are using a non-standard extension. C++ standard doesn't have VLA ([variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)).

Variable length arrays are typically allocated on "stack" and is prone to stack overflow. If length of the array is too big, you will have undefined behaviour. Worse, you can't easily know the "right" size for the array, either. For that reason, VLAs are best avoided. You could use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you should try a better approach(Textbook approach) i.e to count how many times 0,1 and 2 are occurring and then assigning them in ascending order or please explain what approach you are using in your code.

```
void sort012(int a[], int n)
{
    int count[3]={};
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        count[a[i]]++;
    }
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        int temp=count[i];
        while(temp--){
            a[j]=i;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

its an easy and efficient approach in terms of time and space complexity

Comment: The approach they're using is the three-way partitioning from the [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem).

Answer (score 0):

**This Code Will be not be executed for this testcase like 012210
because if you keep mid=1 then it doesn't comparing the 1 at index=1 and it is leaving that one the output will become 010122...leaving 1 at index 1 and in that whenever you got high at last index is 0..so for a correct approach it should swap(arr[right],arr[1])but low is at 0 index then mid is just simply moving so missing the updating of value at index 1 from high so making mid=0 our code will corrects that case
This Optimised Code will works for all the testcase**

```py
#Optimal Approach 

#Dutch National Flag Approach

def sort012(arr, n) :
    low,mid,right=0,0,n-1  #making mid=0 to compare all possibilities
    while mid<=right:
        if arr[mid]==0:
            arr[low],arr[mid]=arr[mid],arr[low]
            low+=1
            mid+=1
        elif arr[mid]==1:
            mid+=1
        else:
            arr[mid],arr[right]=arr[right],arr[mid]
            right-=1
    return arr
#Time complexity:O(N)
#Space Complexity:O(1)
```

Comment: This does not answer *What is wrong with the code in the question?*.

Comment: (*ones* (like twos) and *once* (like twice) may sound similar, but are quite different.)